# ESLint React JSX Closing Tag / Parsing Error

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I'm trying to set up ESLint on my React project.

Installed both `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-react` locally on my project.

Also using the VSCode ESLint extension (but I tried this without this extension and I also get the same linting errors).

Below you can see my .eslintconfig.json file and dependencies versions. I've got JSX enabled.

I keep getting errors on these closing tags.

What seems to be the problem? I can't make this errors go away and it's just simple closing tags.

Thanks a lot.

[image: index.js file]

[image: app.js file]

[image: ESLint errors]

[image: .eslintconfig file]

[image: package.json file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was being caused by some kind of conflict between the `eslint` package and some of `babel` packages, because when I did a clean install using only `eslint` and `react` that `.eslintrc.json` configuration worked perfectly.

I didn't have `babel-eslint` installed before and I was using the default parser that comes with  `eslint`.

To solve the problem I had to install the `babel-eslint` package and use it as the parser for the `eslint` package. Everything is working fine now and those errors are gone.

Even though the `babel-eslint` docs says that you don't have to use it just because you're using `babel`, in my situation, using it along with `babel` and `eslint` solved the problem.

New `eslint` config file:

[image]